# Getting: "Failed to fetch metadata" when starting up Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter, plotly-dash, jupyter-lab

I am using JupyterLab as my IDE and I have a couple of packages installed. Namely, the 'jupyterlab-dash' and 'juptyerlab-plotly' packages. My issue is when I go to launch 'juptyer lab' from terminal, I notice the following error:

`Failed to fetch package metadata for 'jupyterlab-dash': URLError(gaierror(8, 'nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))`

I'm not sure why this error is popping up but I've noticed this error only pops up when I have no internet connection (working on a train etc.). Could it be because these packages are trying to call something as I launch and because I don't have an internet connection it raises the error?

In the end I am able to use JupyterLab and the packages as intended (at-least it seems), but I'm curious why this error to 'fetch metadata' appears?

Thanks,

Comment: I am having the same problem too. Did you get it resolved @Jack?

Comment: Sadly nope. Not sure why it says this.